# How can I access a test environment from another cpp file?

Tags: c++, c++17, googletest

I want to register a `std::filesystem::path` instance on the main of my test and access from all my tests. I followed the documentation and registered a child of `::testing::Environment` in my main with a public `static inline` property but I'm at a loss on how to read that variable (the registered environment) in my tests, ideally in my test fixtures.

Comment: Not sure this will solve your problem but what about simply create a static variable in your fixture and initialize it from the `main`?

Comment: And define the fixture in a header file?

Comment: Yes indeed at least it is worth a try.